# Using RxJava to write an infinite stream of grouped events to rotating files

Tags: java, rxjs, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm trying to achieve the following behavior:

- Have a stream of events periodically polled/generated (short duration, say 1 second)
- Events are then grouped according to some internal trait.
- Each group of events is written to a matching file **immediately** (this is a crucial of the behavior I want to maintain)
- Files are expected to be reused for matching groups (have the same key) on subsequent events until they are sealed/rotated
- Upon a longer duration (say, 5 seconds) file are sealed/rotated and acted upon using additional subscribers

I wrote the following sample code to achieve the above behavior:

```java
    private static final Integer EVENTS = 3;
    private static final Long SHORTER = 1L;
    private static final Long LONGER = 5L;
    private static final Long SLEEP = 100000L;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        val files = new DualHashBidiMap<Integer, File>();

        Observable.just(EVENTS)
                .flatMap(num -> Observable.fromIterable(ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(num).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())))
                .groupBy(num -> Math.abs(num % 2))
                .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delay(SHORTER, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .map(group -> {
                    val file = files.computeIfAbsent(group.getKey(), Unchecked.function(key -> File.createTempFile(String.format("%03d-", key), ".txt")));
                    group.map(Object::toString).toList().subscribe(lines -> FileUtils.writeLines(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name(), lines, true));
                    return file;
                })
                .buffer(LONGER, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                .distinct(File::getName)
                .doOnNext(files::removeValue)
                .doOnNext(file -> System.out.println("File - '" + file + "', Lines - " + FileUtils.readLines(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                .subscribe();
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP);
    }
```

While it works as expected (set aside thread safety issue for map access for now, I'm using the bidi-map from `commons-collections4` just for the sake of demonstration), I was wondering if there's a way to implement the above functionality in a **pure** RX form, without relying on external map access?

Note that it's **crucial** for the files to be written immediately upon on group creation, meaning we must make the file live beyond the scope of generated event groups

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.. I could be wrong, but I don't think you can avoid having a `Map` of `Files` somewhere in the pipeline.

I think my solution could be further cleaned up, but it seems to accomplish the following:

- Removes the need for bidirectional mapping
- Avoids the need to call `Map.remove(...)`

I'm proposing you treat the `Map` of `Files` being written as a distinct `Observable`, emitting a brand new `Map` at the slower interval:

```
    Observable<HashMap<Integer, File>> fileObservable = Observable.fromCallable(
                () -> new HashMap<Integer, File>() )
            .repeatWhen( completed -> completed.delay( LONGER, TimeUnit.SECONDS ));
```

Then in your event `Observable`, you can call `.withLatestFrom( fileObservable, ( group, files ) -> {...} )` (*note: this block is incomplete still*):

```
    Observable.just( EVENTS )
        .flatMap( num -> Observable.fromIterable(
                ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints( num ).boxed().collect( Collectors.toList() )))
        .groupBy( num -> Math.abs( num % 2 ))
        .repeatWhen( completed -> completed.delay( SHORTER, TimeUnit.SECONDS ))
        .withLatestFrom( fileObservable, ( group, files ) -> {

            File file = files.computeIfAbsent(
                    group.getKey(),
                    Unchecked.function( key -> File.createTempFile( String.format( "%03d-", key ), ".txt" )));

            group.map( Object::toString ).toList()
                .subscribe( lines -> FileUtils.writeLines(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name(), lines, true ));

            return files;
        } )
```

So far so good, you're getting your latest set of `Files` supplied alongside your events. Next you've got to process the `Files`. I think you can do that using `distinctUntilChanged()`. It should be pretty efficient since it will call `HashMap.equals(...)` under the covers and the `Map` object's identity isn't changing most of the time. `HashMap.equals(...)` first checks for same identity.

Since at this point you're really interested in processing the *previous* set of emitted `Files` rather than the current, you could use the `.scan(( prev, current ) -> {...} )` operator. With that, here's the completed code block from above:

```
    Observable.just( EVENTS )
        .flatMap( num -> Observable.fromIterable(
                ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints( num ).boxed().collect( Collectors.toList() )))
        .groupBy( num -> Math.abs( num % 2 ))
        .repeatWhen( completed -> completed.delay( SHORTER, TimeUnit.SECONDS ))
        .withLatestFrom( fileObservable, ( group, files ) -> {

            File file = files.computeIfAbsent(
                    group.getKey(),
                    Unchecked.function( key -> File.createTempFile( String.format( "%03d-", key ), ".txt" )));

            group.map( Object::toString ).toList()
                .subscribe( lines -> FileUtils.writeLines(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name(), lines, true ));

            return files;
        } )
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .scan(( prev, current ) -> {

            Observable.fromIterable( prev.entrySet() )
                .map( Entry::getValue )
                .subscribe( file -> System.out.println( "File - '" + file + "', Lines - " +
                                FileUtils.readLines( file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 )));

            return current;
        } )
        .subscribe();

    Thread.sleep( SLEEP );
```

A little lengthier than your original solution, but might solve a couple of issues.

Comment: Emitting the map  itself as an observable and using combine with latest is a bright idea :)
Sounds promising. I'll test its validity in the real world application (the above code is just a sample, of course) and approve your answer if it works.

Thank you for the effort you put in!

Comment: Ok, this seems to be a valid approach. A few comments:

1) `distinctUntilChanged` works well because map equality first test for object level identity ( `==`) which is always true, and then proceesd to content comparison, which will always be false because the values are temp files generated dynamically.

2) I used buffer(2,1).map(maps -> Observable.fromIterable(maps.iterator().next().values())) in order transform the observable into an observable of files instead of scan.

Again - appreciate your help